# Axios: Using and passing response variables to middleware route functions

Tags: node.js, express, axios, middleware

I have a middleware implemented with Axios: It calls  2 or 3 routes, the first 2 route-functions return single values with res.locals.someVariable and next() function, e.g:

```
exports.getReservierungenByMonth = function(req,res,next) {

        Produkt.aggregate([
            {
                "$unwind":"$DemonstratorWerte"
            },
            {   
                "$match": {"DemonstratorWerte.Demonstrator" : +req.params.demo_id/*, "ProduktReserviert.Status": false*/}
            },

            .......
            {
                "$addFields": { 
                    "Monat": { 
                        "$let":  { 
                            "vars": {  
                                "monthsInStrings": [, "Januar", "Februar", "Maerz", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"] 
                            }, 
                            "in": {  
                                "$arrayElemAt": ['$$monthsInStrings','$Monat'] 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        ]).exec(function(err, prod) {
                if (err) {
                        res.json(err);
                    }

                else {                  
                    res.locals.reservierungen = reservierungenArray;
                    //res.locals.reservierungen = prod;
                    next();
                }
            })//.then((res) => res.json())
        };
```

then, my third router link from axios uses those res.locals variables to query and aggregate some data, e.g:

```
exports.getStornierungenReservierungen = function(req,res,next) {

    stornierungen = res.locals.stornierungen;
    reservierungen = res.locals.reservierungen; 

    Produkt.aggregate([ 
        {
            $project: {
            "Alle": { $concatArrays: [ stornierungen, reservierungen ]}
            }
        },
        {...}
```

Then, my third router link in returns the aggregated data from the 2 previous res.locals values including the last route function:

```
router.route('/Middleware/sdasdhgrt/:demo_id').get(function(req,res,next) {
    axios.all([
      axios.get(`http://localhost:2323/D/L4C/a/${req.params.demo_id}`),
      axios.get(`http://localhost:23325/D/Ls/b/${req.params.demo_id}`),
      //axios.get(`http://localhost:53355/4Z/L4C/3/${req.params.demo_id}`)--->> needs the res.locals values!
    ])
    .then(axios.spread(function (result1,result2,result3) {
      res.send({result1,result2});
      res.write(JSON.stringify({
        result1, result2, result3
      }));
      //console.log('Result1: ', result1.data);
      //console.log('Result2: ', result2.data);
      //console.log('Result3: ', result3.data);
    })).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    }); 
    });
```

My question now is: How can I pass the res.locals values from the 2 router links to the third link using axios? In Express, I just did this by using next() function...

Answer (score 0):

In this code :

```
axios.all([
  axios.get(`http://localhost:2323/D/L4C/a/${req.params.demo_id}`),
  axios.get(`http://localhost:23325/D/Ls/b/${req.params.demo_id}`),
  //axios.get(`http://localhost:53355/4Z/L4C/3/${req.params.demo_id}`)--->> needs the res.locals values!
])
```

Couldn't you just use the first two requests as part of the `axios.all()` and then use `.then(callback)` to make the third request? So something like:

```
axios.all([
  axios.get(`http://localhost:2323/D/L4C/a/${req.params.demo_id}`),
  axios.get(`http://localhost:23325/D/Ls/b/${req.params.demo_id}`),
])
.then((done) => { 
 axios.get(`http://localhost:53355/4Z/L4C/3/${req.params.demo_id}`)
 done();
})
.then((done) => {
  //the rest of your code
  done();
})
```

EDIT:

Quite honestly, I would also just use async/await kinda like this (might be missing some stuff, I didn't test this at all, just wrote it out the top of my head):

```
try {
        let dataToUse = [], promises = [];
        let now = new moment();
        promises.push(axios(`http://localhost:2323/D/L4C/a/${req.params.demo_id}`));
        promises.push(axios(`http://localhost:23325/D/Ls/b/${req.params.demo_id}`));

        const responses = await Promise.all(promises);
        dataToUse = responses.map(response => response.data);
        //make third request with data
        axios.get(`http://localhost:53355/4Z/L4C/3/${dataToUse.parameter}`);

        // Send your data with res.send();
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send({
            //error info
        });
    }
```

Cheers,

Comment: hmm yeah maybe, in the then I can pass the results from the 2 previous axios requests to my function callback and then do what I want. However, I am not sure if I can just pass results as a url parametre like ${data...}. Normally, I would pass data in Node with next() and just go to my next routing controller function  with a callback and retrieve the value with res.locals.someData...  I couldn't find a documentation in axios about an equivalent thing.. usually, one passes data in the body of a request and not in url-string or not?

Comment: @MMM I'm not sure I follow. It depends on your request/api. If you're making a GET request, parameters are passed through the URL usually in the following form (for a REST API) : `/users/{userNumber}`. Although, if it's a POST request, then yes, the body of your request will most likely be some JSON data.